# Godot firebase password recovery assistance

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, godot

so I watched a couple tutorials online, and have the login, and register, however no one ever puts up "send password recovery" tutorial, which I did find the firebase documentation for it:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-send-password-reset-email

HOWEVER when i try and use the HTTP request, and run it... it gives me error message "Failed to Connect"... not sure where else to look for more detail, but thats all i get... here is my code below:

```
const _RECOVER_URL := "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:sendOobCode?key=" + API_KEY

func recover(email:String, http: HTTPRequest) -> void:
var body := {
"email": email
}
http.request(_RECOVER_URL, [], false, HTTPClient.METHOD_POST, to_json(body))
var result := yield(http, "request_completed") as Array
if result[1] == 200:
current_token = _get_token_id_from_results(result)

func _on_RecoverBtn_pressed():
if EmailAddress.text.empty():
notification.text = "Please Enter Email Address"
return
Firebase.recover(EmailAddress.text, http)
```

Comment: The linked documentation says you need `"requestType": "PASSWORD_RESET"` on your request. *I don't know if there are other valid values, however the documentation makes it clear that `requestType` is not optional.*

Comment: hey thanks for that, good catch, however i added that into my code:                      
     ```func recover(email:String, http: HTTPRequest) -> void:
 var body := {
  "requestType": "PASSWORD_RESET",
  "email": email
 }              ``` and still says "Failed to Connect", not sure why... i wish it had some  more info to go off of :(

Comment: I had a look at Godot source and... Well, if the message is from what I think it is, then it is quite literal, it can't connect. Are other requests against identitytoolkit.googleapis.com working? How about to other domains? If they aren't working, I'd say firewall or DNS or certificates. If they are working, then drill deeper on the request. I see the documentation sets a content type header in the example, perhaps you need that? Are you able to do the same request with other software from your machine? Edit: from C# perhaps?

Comment: Thank you for the info, the other requests work fine... Its just the request to reset password doesnt work. But you mentioned in the documentation sets a content type header? Can you maybe point to it... You may be right and might be missing it... Or another idea you mentioned I should try this in C#, I will try that as well... As for drilling down... Not sure how to drill deeper or were to find logs etc.

Comment: In your linked documentations, where it says sample request, it has a header "Content-Type: application/json". I don't know if it is useful, but searching for the url I found this: https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/rest/v1/accounts/sendOobCode - the option to test it is connecting to https://content-identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:sendOobCode (I'm guessing that is an end point for testing, but I'm not Firebase expert, and I could not find information about)